# Association Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, associative-array

I am having a problem with an association:

Battalion
  :has_many soldiers

Soldiers 
  :has_many primaries

I need to do this 
    @bseniorleads=(@user.battalion.soldiers.find(:all, :conditions => ["seniorleader = ?", "Yes"]))
then
    @seniorspouse=(@bseniorleads.primaries.find(:all, :conditions => ["relationship = ?", "Spouse"]

This gives me an undefined method for primaries, I assume because the bseniorleads is an array?

Basically I don't know how to do this they right way but I need to be able to query a group from one model that meets a condition and then take that result and find the people from another model that belong to them. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this (assuming you only needed the `@bseniorleads` instance variable in the second query):

```
@senior_spouse = @user.battalion.soldiers.find(
   :all,
   :select => 'primaries.*',
   :joins => [:primaries],
   :conditions => ["seniorleader = ? and primaries.relationship = ?", "Yes", "Spouse"]
)
```

I haven't checked that yet, but I think it should get you pretty close.

You might want to check out these two rails guides, which certainly helped me better understand ActiveRecord associations and querying:

- [ActiveRecord Querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)
- [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have checked out the guides and they are a huge help, I am so new to programming that anything complex throws me. This has been a big help in understanding what I need to do and how it works.